# How do iterate over Grease pencil selection with python?

Tags: python, grease-pencil

Is there a grease pencil equivalent for bpy.context.selected_objects but for strokes or points?

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate variable.  Grease Pencil strokes are objects like any other object and so are included in (or excluded from) `bpy.context.selected_objects`.

If you want just the selected Grease Pencil objects, you can use the list comprehension `[object for object in bpy.context.selected_objects if object.type = 'GPENCIL']`

Comment: This makes sense but i was hoping for something that would list the strokes or points as being selected.